# Почему <blockquote> внутри <p> выдает ошибку?

Tags: html, html5, adobe-brackets

Почему `<blockquote>` внутри `<p>` выдает ошибку?
И все при этом функционирует в браузере вполне нормально, цитирование на месте, весь дальнейший документ отображается корректно. 
Но Brackets показывает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вопрос закроют ...и минусов навтыкают

Comment: Почему? Все ведь по делу спросил. Текст кликабелен, есть скрин

Comment: Почитай внимательно , здесь к этому серьёзно отноcятся : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: я надеюсь помог Вам понять что в вашем вопросе не верно

Comment: @meine есть инфа, что оба тега являются блочными ;-)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теги `<p>` (*параграф*) и `<blockquote>` (*блок цитаты*) — блочные элементы. Но, `<blockquote>`, кроме оформительской, несёт ещё и семантическую нагрузку, определяя блок для цитаты. Исходя из этого — *блок цитаты* может быть разбит на *параграфы*, а *параграф* не может состоять из *блоков цитат*.

Если возникает необходимость разместить цитату в *параграфе*, то используется тег `<q>`, который является строчным по умолчанию.

Comment: Можно ещё ссылку прикрепить на спецификацию тега: https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element